# Registering shortcode in activation hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have been working on a plug-in and I have been trying to add a shortcode inside of a function that is registered as an activation hook. I know the function is being called, because if I add an echo statement inside of the function, WordPress will complain about receiving input after the header has been sent, but the shortcode does not display. However, if I move the `add_shortcode` outside of the function, then everything works fine.

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

This works:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Testing
*/

function short_code($atts) {
    return "This is a test";
}

function activate() {
    add_shortcode('testing', 'short_code');
}

//register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate');
add_shortcode('testing', 'short_code');
```

This Doesn't:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Testing
*/

function short_code($atts) {
    return "This is a test";
}

function activate() {
    add_shortcode('testing', 'short_code');
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate');
//add_shortcode('testing', 'short_code');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [ask] and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Faegy updated my question with a minimal example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`register_activation_hook` only fires once - when the plugin is activated. So your shortcode is only being registered that one time upon activation and is then no longer available.

You should use `add_shortcode` as you have it in the first example. `add_shortcode` is itself a hook, it doesn't need to be inside another hook.

Comment: that works great! I just assumed that `add_shortcode` registered it until `remove_shortcode` was called.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I've had the same problem. I'm still confused as to why it would not register the hook for that shortcode? I've seen instances where a function that adds the shortcode is hooked to `add_action('init', 'the_handler');` and it works?

Comment: When you add an action to init, that action is run every time WordPress is loaded and run. When you add it to register_activation_hook, it is only run when the plugin is being activated. Your short code registration needs to happen every time WordPress is loaded up which is why it works on init. Registering a short code has to happen every time WordPress runs - it’s not like you register it once and it permanently exists. It “registers” every time. You can do it on init, but using add_shortcode is a better practice because that’s what it was built for.